# Compute distance matrix for sequences of unequal lengths

Tags: python, numpy, hierarchical-clustering, distance-matrix, dtw

I have a multiple sequences (with unequal lengths) of the form:

```
series = [ [1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 1],
           [2, 6, 1, 4, 5],
           [3, 5, 6, 7, 1, 4, 8, 7, 9],
           [4, 3, 2, 1],
           ...
           [2, 9, 7, 6, 5]
         ] 
         shape = (38, )
```

The length of the sequences is around 1000-2000. There are 38 sequences in total. I need to perform hierarchical clustering on these, for which I have defined a custom distance measure based on weighted DTW (Dynamic Time Warping):

```
def myMetric(x, y):
    return weighted_dtw(x, y, dist=sd.euclidean)[0]
```

Is there a way to efficiently compute the distance matrix for the above series using *myMetric* as the distance measure? Iterating through the whole series would be *O(n^2)* and is taking take too long for 38 sequences on my system. Additionally, I tried using [sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances.html),

`dist = pairwise_distances(series, metric=myMetric)`

but that requires the series to be of equal lengths, and throws the following error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: You can't compute an O(n^2)-sized output in less than O(n^2) time.

Comment: @user2357112 I do understand that, I was looking for alternate ways to reduce the computation time. For example, dist(u, v) = dist(v, u), so I need to compute only once. I can write my own function, but was wondering if there was a library which already offered a better way.

Comment: You should rewrite your code to take advantage of the [multiprocessing library](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: You could try to pad all you sequences and modify your distance function to handle the padding. Then the processing could be done with numpy at C level code more easily. The complexity would, of course, remain the same.

Comment: @C.Yduqoli I was currently working on the same, definitely sounds reasonable. Thanks!